# How to format LocalDateTime with minutes only (truncate seconds)?

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, localdatetime

I have `LocalDateTime` values and want to make use of the `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` constant to print only up to the *minutes*.

Both testcases fail with:

```
Expected :2020-10-10T15:16
Actual   :2020-10-10T15:16:00
```

But why?

```
assertEquals("2020-10-10T15:16", LocalDateTime.parse("2020-10-10T15:16:17")
                .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));

assertEquals("2020-10-10T15:16", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(
        LocalDateTime.parse("2020-10-10T15:16:17").truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)));
```

Beside that: where is the difference between using the first or second approach to format a `LocalDateTime` value?

Comment: documentation is your friend https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: This does not answer my question in any case why the seconds are still printed though I'm truncating them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You do not need a formatter for your use case

The [`LocalDateTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--) by default omits second-of-minute and nano-of-second fields if they are zero.

> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of
> the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

[`LocalDateTime#truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) sets the second-of-minute and nano-of-second fields to zero.

> Truncation returns a copy of the original date-time with fields
> smaller than the specified unit set to zero. For example, truncating
> with the minutes unit will set the second-of-minute and nano-of-second
> field to zero.

Thus, you do not need a formatter for your use case.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-10-10T15:16:17").truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-10T15:16
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom formatter, `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` will always use `00` for seconds when the date-time is truncated to the minute, because that date format specifies that seconds should be included (and 0 is the value of the seconds field in the date-time).

This should work

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
assertEquals("2020-10-10T15:16", LocalDateTime.parse("2020-10-10T15:16:17")
         //.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES) <-- not needed with that format
           .format(formatter));
```